# Node ExpressJS | How to pass custom query params validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, ecmascript-6

Learning ExpressJS here.
I have a `get` route that expects query params i.e.

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ name: req.query.name, age: req.query.age, club: req.query.club })
})
```

On postman the following `http://localhost:5000/api?name=Messi&age=31&club=Barcelona`

returns 200 with the res.body as:

```
{
    "name": "Messi",
    "age": "31",
    "club": "Barcelona"
}
```

**Question**

How could I write a custom validation where:

- If the requested query param doesn't exist: status 400
- If any of the params are missing i.e (name, age, club) return a response saying that whichever missing param (name, age, and/or age) is required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build an easy validation middleware.

```
function validateQuery(fields) {

    return (req, res, next) => {

        for(const field of fields) {
            if(!req.query[field]) { // Field isn't present, end request
                return res
                    .status(400)
                    .send(`${field} is missing`);
            }
        }

        next(); // All fields are present, proceed

    };

}

app.get('/api', validateQuery(['name', 'age', 'club']), (req, res) => {
  // If it reaches here, you can be sure that all the fields are not empty.
  res.send({ name: req.query.name, age: req.query.age, club: req.query.club })
})
```

You can also use a third party module for validating requests.

- [Express Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator)
- [Express Superstruct](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-superstruct) (*I'm the author*)

Comment: Fantástico. Thank you very much Marcos!

Comment: I'll be sure to check out your library as well! 

Answer (score 6):

The above answers are *correct*, but as someone who has worked with scalable and maintenable APIs, I'd recommend standardizing the validation process of you API using [JSON Schemas](https://json-schema.org/) to define the expected input, and [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) to validate these schemas.

Example usage:

```
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {

    // define precisely the expected shape of the request
    const schema = {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
            name: { type: 'string' },
            age: { type: 'string' },
            club: { type: 'string' }
        },
        required: ['name', 'age', 'club']
    }

    // validate the request
    const ajv = new Ajv();
    const valid = ajv.validate(schema, req.query);
    if(!valid) res.status(400).send(ajv.errors);

    // request is valid. Do whatever
    res.send(req.query);

})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server listening on port 8080'));
```

Response to `/api`:

```
[
    {
        "keyword": "required",
        "dataPath": "",
        "schemaPath": "#/required",
        "params": {
            "missingProperty": "name"
        },
        "message": "should have required property 'name'"
    }
]
```

Response to `/api?name=messi&age=10&club=barcelona`:

```
{
    "name": "messi",
    "age": "10",
    "club": "barcelona"
}
```

Yes it takes a little bit more code, but trust me, it's the way to go if you want to prepare your app for complex and scalable API validation.

Comment: absolutely great answer! Have you used `Joi` before?

Comment: Thank you! Yes I did. The default of Joi is that its schemas are defined only in the JS layer. With AJV and other JSON validators, you can define your schemas in JSON files and import them in your scripts, which gives a big plus in terms of maintanibility.

Comment: Additionally, Joi has its own way of defining structures, whereas JSON Schemas is a standard that is shared by many libraries and entities. Side effects, more docs and less bugs for JSON-based structure definitions.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm looking into AJV now.

Comment: how could we save the AJV schema validation inside of a `validateInput()` helper, so that it could be reusable across multiple http verbs requests while aimng for a DRY approach?

Comment: do you know why AJV schema transcends other files even when is not being required? I had a separate `const schema.js` file that I import on a single route file. However, the required parameters are restraining even other routes on diff files where I don't have `AJV` nor `schema.js` imported. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check value of every params value

```
If(typeof req.query.name == 'undefined' )
 { res.status(400).send('name is missing') }
```

Check for every value

Comment: I recommend using `return` before `res.status...`.

Comment: @NullisTrue i'm writing an answer, give me a few minutes.